# Can I suppress the unchecked warning in this case?

Tags: scala, generics, compiler-warnings

I have (simplified from actual code):

```
class Def[T]

object Fun {
  def unapply[A,B](d: Def[A => B]): Option[A => B] = ???
}

def isFun(d: Def[_]) = d match {
  case Fun(f) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

This produces a warning:

> non-variable type argument A => B in type pattern TypeName.this.Def[A => B] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

I've tried placing `@unchecked` after `Fun(f)`, but this produces an error; and after `f`, which doesn't suppress the warning. Is there any way to remove this warning?

Comment: More code. This is Scala. It is possible to write something that is less than 30 lines of code, compiles and runs! :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I'm wrong, but after browsing the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), I don't believe you can apply the annotation in the right place **without changing your code**.

Since annotations *"may apply to definitions or declarations, types, or expressions"* (*Chapter 11*), you need one of those for your annotation application to be syntactically correct. The two most likely candidates here seem to be either a type or an expression. However, looking at *Chapter 8 Pattern Matching*, it seems

```
 Fun(f)
```

i.e. the statement where you need to apply the annotation to, is neither, since it looks like it corresponds to:

```
 StableId '(' varid ')'
```

none of which seem to fit the bill for either an expression or a type (or any other valid annotation target).

Answer (score 0):

First, can you change the signature of `def isFun(d: Def[_])` to `def isFun[A,B](d: Def[A=>B])`?

If not, the issue is the type erasure. On the JVM, you can't have this code :

```
trait Foo {
  def doStuff(xs:List[Int])
  def doStuff(xs:List[Long])
}
```

At the runtime, you don't have the info of the generics, their type is erased.

So, in your case, the problem is that you can't pattern match against a generic.

Let's see that example in a Scala Worksheet:

```
object Fun {
    def unapply[A, B](xs: List[Int]): Option[Int] = Some(1)
}

def isFun(d: List[_]) = d match {
    case Fun(f) => true
    case _ => false
} 
//> isFun: (d: List[_])Boolean

isFun(List(1.3)) 
//> res0: Boolean = true
```

The generic type that we wanted to pattern match against was Int, but it did work with Float.

So, I think that you should change your approach as this pattern matching is obviously going to be a problem.

Comment: With my actual code in unapply, I do know that the type argument is `A => B`.

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is the pattern-matching in isFun(). There, you pass a `Def[_]` and you don't know what `_` is. So, then, because of the type erasure, it is impossible to do any kind of runtime pattern-matching of the generic. This is why in my example, even though I passed a `List[Float]` it got matched as a `List[Int]`.